# 'this' does not reference current object context during intercept of Binding Behavior

Tags: javascript, aurelia

In an Aurelia app, I am using a binding-behavior.  It looks like this:

`<div id="slider" ej-slider="e-value.two-way:controller.item.progress & intercept:controller.saveChange;" ></div>`

The intercept binding behavior [from here](https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-binding-behaviors/) is binding `controller.saveChange` which does get called.

However, the issue is that within that method, `this` refers not to the controller, but to the binding. So I can't access the methods and properties of the controller which are needed to do the actual save.

This is what the Binding Behavior Looks like:

```
export class InterceptBindingBehavior {

readonly interceptMethods = ['updateTarget', 'updateSource', 'callSource'];

bind(binding, scope, interceptor) {
    let i = this.interceptMethods.length;
    while (i--) {
        let method = this.interceptMethods[i];
        if (!binding[method]) {
            continue;
        }
        binding[`intercepted-${method}`] = binding[method];
        let update = binding[method].bind(binding);
        binding[method] = interceptor.bind(binding, method, update);
    }
}

unbind(binding, scope) {
    let i = this.interceptMethods.length;
    while (i--) {
        let method = this.interceptMethods[i];
        if (!binding[method]) {
            continue;
        }
        binding[method] = binding[`intercepted-${method}`];
        binding[`intercepted-${method}`] = null;
    }
}
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `interceptor.bind(binding, method, update)` here you are explicitly binding the scope of `binding` to the interceptor method, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  But I don't see how to set it to the proper scope.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: Quick fix could be to separate the intercept method into class and method like `interceptor:controller:'saveChanges'`, because then you could something like `interterceptor[methodName].apply(interceptor, [...params])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to my comment, as a quick&dirty fix I would try to pass the class and the method separately as arguments. I tested it and it does work. But maybe some aurelia experts know a better way how to handle this:

**html**

```
<div id="slider" ej-slider="e-value.two-way:controller.item.progress & intercept:controller:'saveChange'"></div>
```

**InterceptBindingBehavior.ts**

```
export class InterceptBindingBehavior {
readonly interceptMethods = ['updateTarget', 'updateSource', 'callSource'];

bind(binding, scope, interceptorClass, interceptorMethod) {
    let i = this.interceptMethods.length;
    while (i--) {
        let method = this.interceptMethods[i];
        if (!binding[method]) {
            continue;
        }
        binding[`intercepted-${method}`] = binding[method];
        let update = binding[method].bind(binding);
        binding[method] = interceptorClass[interceptorMethod].bind(interceptorClass, method, update);
    }
}

unbind(binding, scope) {
    let i = this.interceptMethods.length;
    while (i--) {
        let method = this.interceptMethods[i];
        if (!binding[method]) {
            continue;
        }
        binding[method] = binding[`intercepted-${method}`];
        binding[`intercepted-${method}`] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for taking the time to help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the original InterceptBindingBehavior only supports a method directly on the current binding, it use `interceptor.bind(binding, ...` to ensure `this` is properly set.

But you want `this` to be `controller`, not current binding.

The easy fix is to enforce `this` by yourself.

Either in your component's constructor

```
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(...) {
    // guess you have this.controller = controller; somewhere

    this.controller.saveChange = this.controller.saveChange.bind(this.controller);
  }
}
```

Or in your controller's constructor

```
export class Controller {
  constructor(...) {
    this.saveChange = this.saveChange.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I did not realize that could be done like that.